# How to handle incoming phone call when a application is running

Tags: android, android-activity

How should I handle an incoming call when my application is active? Will my application terminate or pause? it would be nice if you give some examples. thanx.

Answer (score 1):

This topic is discussed in great length in the [Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) article on the Android Dev website.

In short, it will invoke a configuration change, much like changing the screen orientation, and your Activity can get destroyed and recreated. You should be able to deal with that.

You can test it by performing screen orientations, or using 2 emulators and  call each other.

Answer (score 0):

If you handle the Activity lifecycle methods correctly, as explained in http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html, your Activity will be able to behave correctly if it's at the top of the stack when an incoming call is received.